# iterate through multi-level JSON in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I've just really started messing with powershell and JSON.  I know how I would do this in .vbs, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the information from the JSON stream that I've put in a PSCustomObject.

This is about all I can get to:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $new = ConvertFrom-Json $res

PS C:\Windows\system32> $new

5ab3cf621ff74b7d84b6604d268dc2e3
--------------------------------
@{timezone=-18000; org=DWSC; name=dx-dc01; summary=System.Object[]}
```

Here is the entire stream:

```
{
    "5ab3cf621ff74b7d84b6604d268dc2e3": {
        "timezone": -18000,
        "org": "DWSC",
        "name": "dx-dc01",
        "summary": [
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 97,
                "total_size": 3471175680,
                "ts": "2014-12-22",
                "jobs_successful": 97,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 4135197184,
                "ts": "2014-12-21",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 2142773760,
                "ts": "2014-12-20",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 3241462784,
                "ts": "2014-12-19",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 3160975872,
                "ts": "2014-12-18",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 3325648384,
                "ts": "2014-12-17",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 3213957120,
                "ts": "2014-12-16",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 3287087104,
                "ts": "2014-12-15",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 4102248960,
                "ts": "2014-12-14",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 2167602176,
                "ts": "2014-12-13",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 2823620096,
                "ts": "2014-12-12",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 2777434624,
                "ts": "2014-12-11",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 3017865728,
                "ts": "2014-12-10",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 3269979136,
                "ts": "2014-12-09",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 3255396352,
                "ts": "2014-12-08",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 4094169088,
                "ts": "2014-12-07",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 2159005184,
                "ts": "2014-12-06",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 3248604672,
                "ts": "2014-12-05",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 3266557952,
                "ts": "2014-12-04",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 3047322112,
                "ts": "2014-12-03",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 3090918912,
                "ts": "2014-12-02",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 3270432768,
                "ts": "2014-12-01",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 3972825600,
                "ts": "2014-11-30",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 2160855552,
                "ts": "2014-11-29",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 2304687616,
                "ts": "2014-11-28",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 2506697216,
                "ts": "2014-11-27",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            },
            {
                "jobs_aborted": 0,
                "img_total": 98,
                "total_size": 3516776960,
                "ts": "2014-11-26",
                "jobs_successful": 98,
                "jobs_failed": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I guess I just really need to get what's in the `System.Object[]`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
PS C:\> $o = ConvertFrom-Json $json

PS C:\> $o.'5ab3cf621ff74b7d84b6604d268dc2e3'.summary | ft -a

jobs_aborted img_total total_size ts         jobs_successful jobs_failed
------------ --------- ---------- --         --------------- -----------
           0        97 3471175680 2014-12-22              97           0
           0        98 4135197184 2014-12-21              98           0
           0        98 2142773760 2014-12-20              98           0
           0        98 3241462784 2014-12-19              98           0
           0        98 3160975872 2014-12-18              98           0
           0        98 3325648384 2014-12-17              98           0
           0        98 3213957120 2014-12-16              98           0
           0        98 3287087104 2014-12-15              98           0
           0        98 4102248960 2014-12-14              98           0
           0        98 2167602176 2014-12-13              98           0
           0        98 2823620096 2014-12-12              98           0
           0        98 2777434624 2014-12-11              98           0
           0        98 3017865728 2014-12-10              98           0
           0        98 3269979136 2014-12-09              98           0
           0        98 3255396352 2014-12-08              98           0
           0        98 4094169088 2014-12-07              98           0
           0        98 2159005184 2014-12-06              98           0
           0        98 3248604672 2014-12-05              98           0
           0        98 3266557952 2014-12-04              98           0
           0        98 3047322112 2014-12-03              98           0
           0        98 3090918912 2014-12-02              98           0
           0        98 3270432768 2014-12-01              98           0
           0        98 3972825600 2014-11-30              98           0
           0        98 2160855552 2014-11-29              98           0
           0        98 2304687616 2014-11-28              98           0
           0        98 2506697216 2014-11-27              98           0
           0        98 3516776960 2014-11-26              98           0
```

PowerShell seems not to recognize `5ab3cf621ff74b7d84b6604d268dc2e3` as a property name, even though it is expanded when pressing tab. Putting quotes around it works though.

Comment: Thanks Markus.  That got me exactly where I needed to be.

Comment: Propertynames that begin with numbers are considered special and needs to be quoted, "doublequoted" or inside a scriptblock. :-)